# Regex headache

Tags: .net, regex

I want to validate a some C# source code for a scripting engine.  I want to make sure that only System.Math class members may be referenced.  I am trying to create a regular expression that will match a dot, followed by a capital letter, followed by any number of word characters, ending at a word boundry that is NOT preceded by System.Math.

I started with this:

```
(?<!Math)\.[A-Z]+[\w]*
```

Which works fine for:

```
return Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);  // won’t flag this
return Xath.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);  // will flag this
```

It correctly matches .Max when it is not preceded by Math.  However, now that I'm trying to expand the regular expression to include System, I can't get it to work.

I've tried these permutations of the regular expression and more:

```
((?<!System\.Math)\.[A-Z]+[\w]*)
((?<!(?<!System)\.Math)\.[A-Z]+[\w]*)
((?<!System)\.(?<!Math)\.[A-Z]+[\w]*)
((?<!System)|(?<!Math)\.[A-Z]+[\w]*)
((?<!System\.Math)|(?<!Math)\.[A-Z]+[\w]*)
```

Using these statements:

```
return System.Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);
return System.Xath.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);
return Xystem.Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);
```

I've tried everything that I could think of, but it either ALWAYS matches the second element (.Math or .Xath above) or it DOESN'T match ANYTHING.

If anyone would have have mercy on me and point out what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreaciate it.

Thanks in advance,
   Welton

Comment: I thought for sure I had a solution, but now I've rediscovered all your listed expressions and wrecked my brain as well. Very tricky indeed!

Comment: Will `Math.` ever appear on its own, or will it always be preceded by `System.`?

Comment: Have you considered using a compiler (CSharpCodeProvider) and then using the CodeDom object graph to scan for references to things other than System.Math?  This would be bulletproof, more readable, and more flexible.

Comment: I agree with Kirk Woll. Using regular expressions in this case is quite similar to use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: Your zero width negative look behind assertion is overlapping your match...

Comment: Hi guys. Just a little background on my project: I'm using CodeDOM to generate a class to evaluate an expression entered by a user. My class does not import any namespaces, and only references the System namespace. I need to prevent the user from referencing any class besides System.Math., so I want to disallow anything that contains a dot (.) except for System.Math and numbers. I started building up my regex using Math., but my ultimate goal was System.Math. I'm going to go with Alan's original solution, where System is not optional. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to make sure you never start matching a member name anywhere but at the beginning.  Then it's a simple matter of using a lookahead to find out if whatever you're looking at starts with `System.Math.`.  Try this regex:

```
(?<![\w.])(?!(?:System\.)?Math\.)(?:[A-Z]\w*\.)+[A-Z]\w*\b
```

The lookbehind ensures that the match doesn't start in the middle of a word (`\w`) or the middle of a qualified member name (`.`).  Now, if the lookahead fails it can't just jump to the beginning of the next component (e.g, the `Math.` in `System.Math.`) and try again.  It's all or nothing.

However, this *will* match `Math.Max` if it's not preceded by `System.`.  Do you really need that, or was that just an intermediate step in developing a regex for the full name?

EDIT: I went ahead and made the `System.` part optional.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for what you stated in the example, this regex will do it.

`^[\w\s]*?[A-Z]\w+\.[A-Z]\w+\.(?<!System\.Math\.)`

It matches all calls to something OTHER than System.Math.XXX as long as: a) there are two `.` in the call, b) that call is on one line.

```
return System.Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5); // no match
return System.Xath.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5); // match
return Xystem.Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5); // match
System.Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);  // no match
System.Xath.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);  // match
Xystem.Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);  // match
return System.Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5); // no match
return System.Xath.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5); // match
return Xystem.Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5); // match
Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);               // no match - only one '.'
System.Max.Math(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);        // match
```

I agree with the comments though; Any regex is pretty fragile and should only be thought of as a text editor type help. You need a parser if you wish it to be bullet proof.

Comment: @Richard: Did the OP state he wanted to match that ultimately? My understanding was that the `Math.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);` and `Xath.Max(466.89/83.449 * 5.5);` where intermediate developments of his regex...

Comment: Oh well, I'll give you a point anyways, because my attempts have failed quite miserably.  LOL.  You should see what I tried ... it would be negative points for me. ;)